# Android Error : Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, timer

I am Creating one thread inside my Click event. I want to call my webservice repeatedly on particular time thats why i am using Timer event inside my click event but it throws exception that java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() .
if i can not call timer in click event then please give me some hint to do so 
here is my code

```
holder.linear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mo.equals(BUDDYNAMECOPY.get(BUDDYNAMECOPY.indexOf(mo)))) {
                    INDEX = BUDDYNAMECOPY.indexOf(mo);
                    B_Id = BUDDYLIST.get(INDEX).getBuddyUID();

                    tim.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            CurrentLocation location =new CurrentLocation(getApplicationContext());
                            lat=location.getCurrentLatitude();
                            lon=location.getCurrentLongitude();
                            String url=UrlConstant.BASEURL + UrlConstant.GET_LATLONG
                            + JsonDataProcessor.uid + "&buddy_uid="
                            + B_Id;
                            JsonDataProcessor caller=new JsonDataProcessor(url,BuddyList.this,UrlConstant.BUDDYLOCATION);

                        }
                    },0,30000);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same kind of problem.

Comment: I am facing the same error.  What is the correct solution?